# Тире и стилистика речи

Tags: стилистика, пунктуация

Есть предложение:
"Причем решено было построить складской комплекс класса А, которые в Беларуси до этого не были представлены, поэтому нам самостоятельно пришлось заниматься проектированием, внедрением этого, быть по сути первопроходцами".

Мне кажется, что сказать "не были представлены" без всякого слова после - не очень красиво.
И еще: нужно ли тире перед "быть по сути первопроходцами"?
Буду признательна, если поможете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаемый вариант:

"Причем решено было построить складской комплекс класса А, которые до этого в Беларуси представлены не были, поэтому нам самостоятельно пришлось заниматься проектированием и продвижением этого проекта - быть, по сути, первопроходцами".

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1. Перестановка в предложении "которые до этого в Беларуси (пз) представлены не были" меняет соотношение тема-рема.
2. По сути - здесь вводное слово (=по сути говоря).
3. В связи с обособлением вводного слова приходится ставить тире перед обобщающим сказуемым (обозначать обобщение).
4. Вместо "этого" лучше использовать существительное.

Answer (score 1):

Все верно. Но только почему после слова ***комплекс А***  союзное слово " которые" во мн. числе? Здесь союзное слово относится к слову "комплекс" и должно с ним согласоваться.